# How can on autofill a CupertinoTextField input type number

Tags: flutter

Given that flutter, CupertinoTextField inputs can be prefilled only with `TextEditingController`, of which TextEditingController accepts only strings.

What would be the way then to prefill a cupertinoTextField of type number?

```
CupertinoTextField(
 controller: _payAmountController,
          clearButtonMode: OverlayVisibilityMode.editing,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                         horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 16.0),
          placeholder: 'Job Pay e.g 150000',
          keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
             inputFormatters: [
                     WhitelistingTextInputFormatter
                       .digitsOnly,
                     new CurrencyInputFormatter()
                   ],
           }),
```

Comment: Like so: `controller: TextEditingController.fromValue(TextEditingValue(text: "123"))` ? Or I did not understand this question?

Comment: You did, but this will always return but a string. Of which the textfield is supposed to be a number.

Comment: TextField always returns String, even if keyboard type is Number. E.g. ValueChanged<String> onChanged; callback passes value which is always String